# Dirichlet's test and region of convergence

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

we know that by Dirichlet's test  if $\Phi$(x) is bounded and monotonic in region [a,∞) that tends to  0  as x approaches  to ∞ .Let integration of f(x) w.r.t x from a $\to$  t  is bounded for all t≥a .then integration of  f(x)$\Phi$(x) w.r.t x from 0 $\to \infty$ is convergent at $\infty$.

i have few questions about this topic .e.g  discuss the convergence of  integration of $(\frac{sin^m(x)}{x^n})$  from   1 to $\infty$  .answer is  given integral is convergent if  n>m-1.
i want to ask  why there is no possibility for convergence for n < m-1 .

how do  you know that function is divergent in  n < m-1 .

may be there is a function $\Phi$(x) which can be prove given integral is convergent in  m-2

How you know that no such function exists ?

Comment: Please format your question properly **before posting**, e.g., using $\LaTeX$.

Comment: sir please check now thanks